# How to append string with each array of array element

Tags: swift

I have an array of array which contains strings.
ex -

```
array = [["to play","to learn"],["to eat"]]
```

And I have:

```
string = "I like"
```

I want to append string to each element in array
like-

```
array = [["I like to play","I like to learn"],["I like to eat"]]
```

Comment: Use `array.map { $0.map { string + $0 } }`

Comment: Just realized OP wanted a 2D array as result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var prefix = "I like "

let array = [["to play","to learn"],["to eat"]]

let temp = array.map { $0.map { prefix + $0 } }
```